# Windows Workflow 4 Designer error using custom activities with custom libraries

Tags: workflow

I built a custom activity referencing a custom library. When I drop my custom activity into a Windows Workflow 4 designer, I get this error:

Workflow Designer encountered problems with your document

Please check the document for invalid content, namespaces, references or reference loops

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'my custom libary...'

I'm using Visual Studio 2010.

I've tried adding the library to the GAC, cleaning and rebuilding but still get the error. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure that the custom Library is added as a reference to your Rehosted editor.  If not you can you can try is manually load your custom library assembly into the AppDomain.

`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(AssemblyLocation_you_pass_in);`

Hope this helps.